# How to parse updating log into variables

Tags: vb.net, variables, datagridview

I have a log file with constantly updating lines

eg.

```
=LOG.TXT STARTS HERE=
15,12,03,
15,12,36,
=LOG.TXT   ENDS HERE=
```

The fields are hours, minutes, seconds

Time can be 15 or 3pm, for instance

How do I detect when the file updates and when it does, update variables called hour minute and second, then add the variables to a data grid view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `What have you tried so far?` You can look into [**FileSystemWatcher Class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Nothing.. actually. as i have no idea what to do at all. Will sure look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FileSystemWatcher Class** for this : It Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory changes. [Check this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) for MSDN example.

And when a file is modified, you'll write it's content in your datagridview.

```
'Of course, you can get the path dynamically but this is an example
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("d:\temp\testdata.txt")
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
Next
```

Comment: `Please do not feed these questions that lack detail`, this creates an impression that **we will code it for them** and we ***do not*** do that...